# Заполнение значениями комбобкса

Tags: html, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Как сделать так, чтоб в комбобоксе список заполнился значениями из таблицы в базе данных MySQL?

Comment: Давным-давно не верстал ничего. Уточню перед тем, как ответить. Комбобокс - это select?

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = new PDO($connectionString, $user, $pass);
$res = $db->query(“SELECT id, name FROM table”);
echo "<select name='var'>";
while ($obj = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    // $obj - экземпляр объекта stdClass, имена столбцов - свойства объекта
    echo "<option value='{$obj->id}'>{$obj->name}</option>"
}
echo "</select>";
```

Вот таким вот образом можно сделать дропдаунлист. (комбобокс?)

Comment: @Виталий Кустов, не удивлюсь, если теперь вам еще придется отвечать на вопрос о том, что такое PDO )))

Comment: @Deonis, мне долго не было ясно почему в проектах доставшихся мне от кого-либо приходится встречать что-то типа mysql_* или прочей лебеды. Больше года я наблюдаю за форумами, этим ресурсом и ещё много чем. И ВЕЗДЕ спецы советуют начинающим (подают пример, так сказать) использовать эту (и не только эту) древность. А они (новички) думают, что разобрались и делу конец. Караул. Один Попов сколько дерьма натворил. И мой ответ ничему хорошему не учит.

Comment: Мешанина SQL, HTML. Просто времени нет на разъяснение, что мухи должны быть отдельно - котлеты отдельно. Остается только надеяться, что человеку хватит ума не просто взять и скопировать. Я лишь принцип указал. Чистая абстракция